# Como resolver um Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large, no R

Tags: r, plot

Olá estou tentando fazer esse comando:

`tsdiag(m1,gof.lag=20)`

O qual era para realizar 3 garficos dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém aparece o seguinte erro:
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Como poderia resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque o espaço para plotar as imagens é insuficiente para o gráfico que você está plotando. Você pode arrastar as margens para torná-lo maior, ou usar o X11().

```
X11(); tsdiag(m1,gof.lag=20)
```

Dessa forma uma nova janela vai ser criada automaticamente e não haverá problema com o tamanho da imagem.